# How can I pass answerId in action which I am dispatching and answerId is in response its an array object in arrayobject?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, action, ngrx

Consider:

```javascript
private listenToAnswerDeleted() {
   this.uiService.onGlobalEvent('ANSWER_DELETED').subscribe((response) => {
       this.store.dispatch(deleteAnswerAction({'answerId': }));
   });
}
```

In response, I am receiving `answerId` which I want to pass as a parameter in the action which I am dispatching its and array object

---

```
response = {name: 'ANSWER_DELETED', extras: {…}}
extras: {answerId: 'sa68f-k3h45-yi35uy'}
name: "ANSWER_DELETED"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private listenToAnswerDeleted() {
    this.uiService.onGlobalEvent('ANSWER_DELETED').subscribe((response) => {
        const {answerId} = response.extras;
        this.store.dispatch(deleteAnswerAction({answerId}));
    });
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What did you change and why? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69786374/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).